# How can I create sheet-specific named ranges without using Indirect?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I've come up with a useful trick, where I create a named range that refers to the current worksheet, by using the following formula:

```
=RIGHT(CELL("filename",INDIRECT("A1")), LEN(CELL("filename",INDIRECT("A1"))) - FIND("]",CELL("filename",INDIRECT("A1"))))&T(NOW())
```

Where the `INDIRECT`s are there ONLY to stop Excel from Converting `A1` --> `Sheet1!A1`. This works beautifully until I need to call evaluate on it from VBA (which does happen).

Can anyone tell me how either (1) to evaluate a name with this formula in VBA or (2) to get a sheet non-specific reference into the formula. I'd rather not use VBA, since it'll get evaluated ~12000 times, and that's likely to be slow, but if need be, it's probably ok. However, please bear in mind that the sheet it is calculated from is quite unlikely to be `ActiveSheet`, so the context for the `Range()` function in VBA is a little tricky - hence why I'm asking in the first place.

Comment: `how to evaluate a name with this formula in VBA` - something like this should work: `MsgBox Evaluate("myNamedRange")`

Comment: Nah, that gives a Type mismatch. It's due to limitations with the Evaluate function in VBA that basically guarantee if you're evaluating anything within indirect in that is NOT a pure indirect function, you always get `Error 2023`. So `Evaluate("Indirect(A1)")` works, but `Evaluate("=Indirect(A1) + 5") will return an error.

Comment: remove IDIRECT from evaluate: `Evaluate("A1 + 5")` - it evaluates for active sheet

Comment: I'd like to. Unfortunately, when I define a named range, this converts to `=RIGHT(CELL("filename",Sheet1!A1"), LEN(CELL("filename",Sheet1!A1")) - FIND("]",CELL("filename",Sheet1!A1")))&T(NOW())`. Excel doesn't seem to like not defining a sheet to evaluate relative to within named ranges as a whole. Hence this question.

Comment: ok, try to change `Indirect(A1)` to `ADDRESS(1,1)`

Comment: Just tried this (good idea, doesn't work). ADDRESS(1,1) just returns the addres of the cell at 1,1, not the ref to it. If there's a formula that takes this OR a reference, then I could use that to convert, but otherwise we're starting to get back towards Indirect all over again. Which doesn't work in VBA.

Comment: The last part T(now()) puzzles me, this always returns "" for a numeric value...why adding that?

Comment: This is a tip from elsewhere on the web - Now() is volatile, so adding it to end of any formula forces it to be volatile. it *shouldn't* be needed given the `INDIRECT`s, but bear in mind those were added to solve the relativity problem I was facing. Either way without it I was getting a lot more instances where the wrong sheet name would be returned.

Comment: Makes no sense, the formula value never changes for the same worksheet, dont see why it needs to be volatile. But to the matter in hands, you want to retrieve sheet name based on a reference? And how do you pretend to refer to the reference in VBA? using a named range? If so just use names("MyNamedRange").RefersTo

Comment: Mostly important because I'm calculating several sheets at once, so say a formula in `Sheet1` requests the name value, it'll calculate it, then a formula in `Sheet2` does, if volatile, it calculates it, if not, it returns the value for `Sheet1`. I'd in the process of writing a formula parser when I hit this in VBA, so I'd LIKE to to be able to do something like `wksWithTheFormulaIn.Evaluate("__MyName__")` but this doesn't work. Since the name contains a value, nor does using `Range("__MyName__")`.

Comment: Can you replace this with a simple UDF which just return the name of the sheet it's called from? Eg: `SheetName = Application.Caller.Parent.Name`

Comment: Hmm... haven't looked into Application.Caller. If it'll return the range from which a UDF has been executed (which it looks like it will) then that would probably do the job. I'll try it out and see if it works. Will depend on whether the caller is treated as the Name in which the formula is calculated or the cell in which the reference to the name occurs. I suspect, unfortunately, it'll be the latter, but does sound interesting...

Comment: @TimWilliams: That worked beautifully (at least, first couple of tests). I'd forgotten about the Application.Caller property. I'm a little surprised (but quite relieved) that it returns anything when you're evaluating a formula in the context of a name, i.e. you'd think it wouldn't be smart enough to identify the range in which the name is referenced as the caller as opposed to the name itself, but either way, glad it works for the purposes. Interestingly enough it seems to evaluate in code correctly (I'd expect Application.Caller to return null). Post as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach: use a simple UDF which just returns the name of the sheet it's called from.

Eg:

```
Function SheetName()
    SheetName = Application.Caller.Parent.Name
End Function
```

Comment: Just as an addendum, if indirect or equivalent functionality IS needed in this situation, it';s also possible to use the same approach to provide the range back to make the original formula work and leave it evaluatable. However using this approach is a lot more CPU efficient in my case.